# react-semantic-redux-form selectField multiple

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, semantic-ui-react

I am attempting to use react-semantic-redux-form SelectField with the multiple options so a user can select multiple options and if there is one already set then this should show as checked.
I am also using redux-form with semantic0ui-react.
I am getting an error attempting to include multiple selections.

My include statement is:

```
import { SelectField } from "react-semantic-redux-form";
```

My state is:

```
state = {
    relationships: ["some entry"],

    relationshipOptions: [],

};
```

The element code is:

```
<Grid.Column>
<Field
    component={SelectField}
    name="relationships"
    label="Your Relationships"
    options={relationshipOptions}
    multiple
    placeholder="Select to add a relationship"
/>
```

I get the error as below

```
Dropdown `value` must be an array when `multiple` is set. Received type: `[object String]`. 
in Dropdown
```

Comment: what do you have in relationshipOptions?

Comment: The RelationshipOptions is an array of the structure {[ key:'single', value:'single',text:'single], [key:'married',value:'married',text:'married]} The key is enforced as unique by postgresql

Comment: Hey Chris, I have added the working example. Please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have `relationshipOptions` is wrong, it is supposed **array of objects**,

```
const relationshipOptions = [
   { key: "single", value: "single", text: "single" },
   { key: "married", value: "married", text: "married" }
];
```

Here is the working example, [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/svwz2)

Also if you have `single, married` in array. You can do something like this,

```
let relationshipOptions = ["single", "married"].map((x) => {
   return ({
     key: x,
     value: x,
     text: x
  });
});
```